# My PC crashes because of nouveau drivers

Tags: drivers, nouveau

Have problem with my nouveau driver I use i3 if it matters I had a nvdia 340 driver before.

This is the journalctl command log

```
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv84_xuc00f failed with error -2
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: vp: unable to load firmware nouveau/nv84_xuc00f
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: vp: init failed, -2
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv84_xuc103 failed with error -2
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bsp: unable to load firmware nouveau/nv84_xuc103
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bsp: init failed, -2
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv84_xuc00f failed with error -2
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: vp: unable to load firmware nouveau/nv84_xuc00f
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: vp: init failed, -2
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv84_xuc103 failed with error -2
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bsp: unable to load firmware nouveau/nv84_xuc103
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bsp: init failed, -2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the firmware for your GPU. But the firmware should only be necessary for accelerated video decoding, so basic use should be possible without it.

According to https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/VideoAcceleration.html the firmware cannot be redistributed because NVidia forbids redistribution of parts of their driver; it must be redistributed exactly as packaged by NVidia, or not at all.

So you could extract the firmware from a legitimate NVidia driver package yourself:

```
mkdir /tmp/nouveau
cd /tmp/nouveau
wget https://raw.github.com/envytools/firmware/master/extract_firmware.py
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/325.15/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-325.15.run
sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-325.15.run --extract-only
python extract_firmware.py
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/nouveau
sudo cp -d nv* vuc-* /lib/firmware/nouveau/
```